# Coming back from nested functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node/javascript so my problem is likely trivial, but its causing me trouble no less.

I have the following code. It successfully checks a database for both the `Unit` and `Owner` values. The problem is that the code following the if statement `else if (Owner){` executes as expected, however, AFTER that the program never gets to the `return reply(output);` line, which I expect it should.

I think its the way that I am coming back from the `Owner.findOne(...` code.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
exports.sale = {
    tags: ['api'],
    validate : {
        //blah blah blah
    },
    handler : function(request, reply) {
        var output = {
            success: true,
            operations: [],
            epoch: Date.now()
        };

        Unit.findById(request.payload.deviceNumber, function(err, device) {
            if (err) {
                //blah blah blah
            }
            if (device) {
                Owner.findOne({OwnerId: device.Owner}, function(err, Owner) {
                    if (err) {
                        //blah blah blah
                    }
                    else if (Owner){
                        //make changes to output.operations

                    }
                });
            } else {
                output.success = false;

            }
            return reply(output);

        });

    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems in the code.

First, assuming the `if (err)` clause does not have the same `return reply(output)` statement, this means that your code will always do the `return(output)` no matter what as `Unit.findById` is asynchronous. That is, the code is not going to wait for a response from `Unit.findById` to finish and as soon as it calls it, the code will move on and eventually hitting the `return` statement.

Secondly, `Owner.findOne` should have its own `return` statement within the callback function's code block as the code will only travel within it.

Hence for happy path cases where Owner.findOne and Unit.findById executes successfully, you will still receive a response of `output.success = false`.

So, ignoring code readability, to fix the problem - your code should look something like this.

```
Unit.findById(request.payload.deviceNumber, function(err, device) {
    if (err) {
        //blah blah blah
        output.success = false;
        return reply(output);
    }
    if (device) {
       Owner.findOne({OwnerId: device.Owner}, function(err, Owner) {
           if (err) {
              //blah blah blah
              output.success = false;
              return reply(output);
           }
           else if (Owner){
               //make changes to output.operations
           }
           output.success = true;
           return reply(output);
       });
   } else {
       output.success = false;
       return reply(output); 
   }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

`Owner.findOne` is another async function, so you need to move `reply(output)` into the else block where you have `output.success = false;` and add another `reply(output)` call within the callback of `Owner.findOne`.

In your code `return reply(output)` is called **before** the async callback of `Owner.findOne` is executed. In addition you do no need `return`, because you cannot return a value from those callbacks using `return`, the `return` only exit the function there.

```
exports.sale = {
  tags: ['api'],
  validate: {
    //blah blah blah
  },
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    var output = {
      success: true,
      operations: [],
      epoch: Date.now()
    };

    Unit.findById(request.payload.deviceNumber, function(err, device) {
      if (err) {
        //blah blah blah
      }
      if (device) {
        Owner.findOne({
          OwnerId: device.Owner
        }, function(err, Owner) {
          if (err) {
            //blah blah blah
          } else if (Owner) {
            //make changes to output.operations
          }
          reply(output);
        });
      } else {
        output.success = false;
        reply(output);
      }
    });
  }
};
```